# How to update a text file using a condition in PHP?

Tags: php, csv

Hello guys I have a problem with my code. Because I want to create a tool for updating google maps. But my data is in txt file not in database. That's why I am having a hard time coding it. Ok the scenario is:

1. The user will locate it's new location
2. After that, the user will click UPDATE and the program will write a txt file and a csv as well
3. Now the condition is if the user update the map (meaning existing ID) in the txt file or csv. Instead of adding new updated location. It will update only.

Here's my code.

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

    $post_data = $_POST;

    if (!empty($post_data['company_id']) && !empty($post_data['new_lat']) && !empty($post_data['new_long'])) {
        // Save
        $restaurant_id = $post_data['company_id'];
        $new_lat_entry = $post_data['new_lat'];
        $new_long_entry = $post_data['new_long'];

        $datenow = date_create();
        $timestamp = $datenow->format('U');

                    //THIS WILL CREATE ARRAY OF NEW DATA
        $data_add =  array(
            'restaurant_id' => $restaurant_id,
            'new_lat' => $new_lat_entry,
            'new_long' => $new_long_entry,
            'date_updated' => $timestamp
        );

                    //GET THE EXISTING TXT FILE AND UNSERIALIZE IT
        $data = unserialize(file_get_contents('addresses.txt'));
        $data[] = $data_add; //ADD LATEST DATA TO ARRAY

                    //SERIALIZE UPDATED ARRAY
        $serialize_data = serialize($data);
        file_put_contents("addresses.txt", $serialize_data, LOCK_EX); //write the text file
                    //WRITE UPDATE OR NEW txtfile
        $array = unserialize(file_get_contents('addresses.txt'));

                    //CREATE CSV
        $file_input = fopen("addresses.csv","w");
        foreach ($array as $row) {
            fputcsv($file_input, $row);
        }

        fclose($file_input);


    } else {
        // prompt missing inputs
    }
```

What function do I need to use for that? That's all guys thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are opening file to write and fp(filepointer) is at the beginning of file. it will always write from beginning of file.

```
    $file_input = fopen("addresses.csv","w");
```

replace that "w" with "a" or "a+"  (+ = read/write both)

```
    $file_input = fopen("addresses.csv","a");
```

Read more here http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php

This code is working well :

```
   <?php

   $data =  array(
        'restaurant_id' =>"1",
        'new_lat' => "2",
        'new_long' => "3",
        'date_updated' => "4"
    );

    $file_input = fopen("test.csv","a+");
        fputcsv($file_input, $data);

    fclose($file_input);

   ?>
```

You are trying to read all file contents and write it back to file? Why is it necessary? Simply add the new data at the end of file!

Comment: Same issue. I used both. :(

Comment: let me check. It cant be an issue. I will execute code and get back to  you.

Comment: Ok I am really glad that you helped me with it. Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Okay. I just modified answer to add working code. However, I am not why you are using file_put_contents() there?

Comment: What should I need to use? fopen()?

Comment: Yep, steps would be as follows: (1)create array, which you are doing already! (2) open file in "a" or "a+" mode (3) no need to go for loop as you will simply enter the latest data. Write it to file. (4) close the file. I modified answer for an example with hard-coded data.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41156/discussion-between-pramod-and-rochelle-canale)